# Opening SQL Server from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have come across a tricky little problem and here and it is to do with opening a SQL Server database

The calling code is

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dbTools = new DataBaseTools();

    if (dbTools.DbWorks)
    {
        label3.Text = "Worked";
    }
    else
    {
        label3.Text = "Try Again";
    }

    label3.AutoSize = true;    
}
```

and the code for connecting to the server is

```
namespace LeatherCorset
{
  public class DataBaseTools
  {
    private Boolean dbWorks;
    private SqlConnection myConn;

    public DataBaseTools(){        
         dbWorks = false;
         InitialiseDatabase();
    }

    private void InitialiseDatabase(){
         myConn = new SqlConnection();
         String  ConnString = 
            "Server=KEITH\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Corset;Trusted_Connection=Yes";

         myConn.ConnectionString = ConnString;
         try{
            if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open){
              dbWorks = true;
            }
         }catch (SqlException ex) {
              dbWorks = false;
         }
    }

    public Boolean DbWorks{
        get { return dbWorks; }
        set { dbWorks = value; }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the debugger it comes up with `connString` with having the value of null.

- The name of the server is `DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS`
- The name of the database is `Corset`
- The owner is `Desktop\Keith`

I am lost at this point in how to get to connect to SQL Server from c#

I would appreciate any advice and help

Comment: ConnString is null when debugging? Have you done a build recently? What line is the debugger display connstring as null?

Comment: This appears to be wrong: `Server=KEITH\\SQLEXPRESS` - according to your post, the server name is `DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS` - not `KEITH\SQLEXRPESS` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you have opened the connection using `Open()`. Also, it is better practice here to initialize the `SqlConnection` with the correct string. Try something like

```
bool dbWorks = false;
sting cs = "Data Source=KIETH\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Corsit;Trusted_Connection=Yes";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            dbWorks = true;
        }
    }   
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Can't see how ConnString is null, I think you may be having some debugging issues, that said, try this:

```
            String  ConnString = "Server=KEITH\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Corset;Trusted_Connection=Yes";
            using (myConn = new SqlConnection(ConnString)) // This will make sure you actually close the DB
            {
                myConn.Open(); // You need to open the connection
                try
                {
                    if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        dbWorks = true;
                    }
                }

                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    dbWorks = false;
                }
           }
```

I'd also recommend actually taking out the try/catch, because you're hiding an exception that may tell you everything that's going wrong.